# Best Way To Load My Own Classes Into Slim Framework

Tags: php, api, lazy-loading, slim

I have created a set of classes that interact with a third party API, I was wondering what the best method of loading these classes into my application made with the Slim framework?
Would lazy loading be the best option?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used Composer to install Slim, you should already have access to an easy to use autoloader.  Just add in your classes, usually I'd recommend PSR4.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4